# Get data details reference by foreign key Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two tables:

Vehicle type:

```
TYPEID   TYPENAME
1        CAR
2        TRUCK
```

Vehicle

```
VEHICLEID TYPEID VEHICLENO
1          1      XX-XX-XX-XXXX
2          2      XX-XX-XX-XXXX
```

When I get all vehicle data using Entity Framework, then it will like:

```
{
    VEHICLEID : 1,
    TYPE : { TYPEID : 1, TYPENAME : 'CAR' },
    VEHICLENO : XX-XX-XX-XXXX
}
```

**NOTE**: I am using ASP.NET MVC, import database (`.edmx`). Please help for create viewmodel and this type of output.

Comment: Do you have any code yet?  Are you using C# or VB?

Comment: No, Only import .edmx. I want to create ViewModel for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was a bit slow but to build on what @Saket posted:

**ViewModels**:

```
public class VehicleViewModel{
    public int vehicleId { get; set; }
    public string VehicleNo { get; set; }
    public VehicleType vehicleType { get; set; }
}

public class VehicleType{
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
}
```

This may not be exact as I do not know your DB structure but this would be a good starting point of code to populate your viewModel(s):

```
public IList<VehicleViewModel> GetAllVehicles(){
    var results = new List<VehicleViewModel>();
    using(var db = new DbContext()){
        var rawDbData = db.Vehicles.Include("VehicleTypes").ToList();
        foreach(var rawData in rawDbData){
            results.add(new VehicleViewModel{
                vehicleId = rawData.VehicleId,
                VehicleNo = rawData.VehicleNo,
                vehicleType = new VehicleType{
                    TypeId = rawData.VehicleTypes.TypeId,
                    TypeName = rawData.VehicleTypes.TypeName
                }
            })
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check if below suits for your `ViewModel`:

```
public class VehicleDetails
{
    public int VehicleID { get; set; }
    public VehicleType Type { get; set; }
    public string VehicleNo { get; set; }
}

public class VehicleType
{
    public int TypeID { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
}
```